# Apache Spark map and reduce with passing values

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I have a simple `map` and `reduce` job over an RDD loaded from Cassandra.
The code looks something like this

```
sc.cassandraTable("app","channels").select("id").toArray.foreach((o) => {

  val orders = sc.cassandraTable("fam", "table")
    .select("date", "f2", "f3", "f4")
    .where("id = ?", o("id")) # This o("id") is the ID i want later append to the finished list

  val month = orders
    .map( oo => {
      var total_revenue = List(oo.getIntOption("f2"), oo.getIntOption("f3"), oo.getIntOption("f4")).flatten.reduce(_ + _)
      (getDateAs("hour", oo.getDate("date")), total_revenue)
    })
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
})
```

So this code summs the revenue up and returns something like this

```
(2014-11-23 18:00:00, 12412)
(2014-11-23 19:00:00, 12511)
```

Now I want to save this back to a Cassandra Table `revenue_hour` but i need the ID somehow in that list, something like that.

```
(2014-11-23 18:00:00, 12412, "CH1")
(2014-11-23 19:00:00, 12511, "CH1")
```

How can I make this work with more then just a (key, value) list? How can i pass along more values, which should not be transformed, instead just passed through to the end so I can save it back to Cassandra?

Comment: I don't know the context where this code is used, but it would look more natural to me to calculate orders by ID for all IDs. As it stands right now, it's not a good case for using Spark. Probably doing the query by 'usual' programmatic means and running a local computation over the results would be a lot faster.  That said, all you need is to add 'id' to the fields in the `.select("id", ...)`

Comment: Thanks for responding, maasg. I updated the question and gave the code more context. In the `channels` table are all the ids possible stored. We iterate over them and catch the revenue for every id, aggregate it and write it into an C* table. Is this a good case for using Spark? I couldn't quite follow your advice, maybe you could rephrase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use a class and work with it through the flow.  I mean, define RevenueHour class

```
case class RevenueHour(date: java.util.Date,revenue: Long, id: String)
```

Then built an intermediate RevenueHour in the map phase and then another one in the reduce phase.

```
val map: RDD[(Date, RevenueHour)] = orders.map(row => 
  (
    getDateAs("hour", oo.getDate("date")), 
    RevenueHour(
      row.getDate("date"),
      List(row.getIntOption("f2"),row.getIntOption("f3"),row.getIntOption("f4")).flatten.reduce(_ + _),
      row.getString("id")
    )
  )
).reduceByKey((o1: RevenueHour, o2: RevenueHour) => RevenueHour(getDateAs("hour", o1.date), o1.revenue + o2.revenue, o1.id))
```

I use o1 RevenueHour because both o1 and o2 will have same key and same id (because the where clause before).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, that code looks nice. I formatted it a bit, because i had a hard time figuring out what stuff belongs where, i will check i out right away.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't test the code, but I hope you understand well.

Comment: Alright, the structure looks good but when i run the code i ran into a serialization problem whenever i wanna do `count` on `val map` or `first` or something like that. Error is `Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable:` I thought case class is serializable by default?

Comment: Have you tried add "extends Serializable" to the case class?

Comment: Jap did that, didn't help though. Here's the line `case class Revenue(date: String, revenue: Long, id: String) extends Serializable`.

Comment: Can you share the whole stacktrace? case class is serializable by default, are you sure that error is in this line?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I put it all in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MichaelHirn/66fa49723e537f4a130d)

Comment: You are using sparkContext within foreach method when SparkContext is not Serializable.  I couln't help you because I don't understand what are you trying to do? (because XXXX :). To array and then foreach it's weird, are you loading two different tables from cassandra? In this case, maybe you could use joinRDD.

Comment: Upps, stripped some information there. I updated and commented the gist code. Are you sure, it is because of the foreach? When i ran the code with a normal two list `(date, revenue)` this error didn't haben. Back then i also could do `month foreach println` which is causing now that serializable bug. The class of `val month` after the map and reduce is actually `class org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65535/discussion-between-gasparms-and-michael-hirn).

Answer (score 1):

The approach presented on the question is sequencing the processing of data by iterating over a array of ids and applying a Spark job on only a (potentially small) subset of the data.

Without knowing how is the relation between the 'channels' and 'table' data, I see two options to fully utilize the ability of Spark of processing data in parallel:

### **Option 1**

If the data on the 'table' table (called "orders" from here on) contains all the set of ids that we require in the report, we could apply the reporting logic to the whole table:

Based on the question, we will use this C* schema:

```
CREATE TABLE example.orders (id text,
      date TIMESTAMP,
      f2 decimal,
      f3 decimal,
      f4 decimal,
      PRIMARY KEY(id, date)
);
```

It makes is a lot easier to access cassandra data by providing a case class that represents the schema of the table:

```
case class Order(id: String, date:Long, f2:Option[BigDecimal], f3:Option[BigDecimal], f4:Option[BigDecimal]) {
    lazy val total = List(f2,f3,f4).flatten.sum
}
```

Then we can define an rdd based on the cassandra table. When we provide the case class as type, the spark-cassandra driver can directly perform a conversion for our convenience:

```
val ordersRDD = sc.cassandraTable[Order]("example", "orders").select("id", "date", "f2", "f3", "f4")

val revenueByIDPerHour = ordersRDD.map{order => ((order.id, getDateAs("hour", order.date)), order.total)}.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

And finally save back to Cassandra:

```
revenueByIDPerHour.map{ case ((id,date), revenue) => (id, date, revenue)}
    .saveToCassandra("example","revenue", SomeColumns("id", "date", "total"))
```

### **Option 2**

if the ids contained in the ("app","channels") table should be used to filter the set of ids (e.g. valid ids), then, we can join the ids from this table with the orders. The job will be similar to the previous on, with the addition of:

```
val idRDD = sc.cassandraTable("app","channels").select("id").map(_.getString)
val ordersRDD = sc.cassandraTable[Order]("example", "orders").select("id", "date", "f2", "f3", "f4")
val validOrders = idRDD.join(ordersRDD.map(order => (id,order))
```

These two ways illustrate how to work with Cassandra and Spark, making use of the distributed nature of Spark's operations. It should also be considerably faster then executing a query for each ID in the 'channels' table.

Comment: Thanks maasg, for your awesome answer. The code looks really sexy and helps me a lot to refactor my current code base. Option 1 is actually the one i use. I have one question though. For option 1 we select now every row in the orders table, could that lead to a slower cassandra response speed, if the data is stored across multiple nodes, or doesn't that matter? Could i actually improve the Select speed of a whole table? Is the select speed depended on table size or throughput?

Comment: Getting data from multiple nodes should be faster as you're able to parallelize the data ingestion. Select speed will depend both on table size (how much data) and throughput (how much data can I transport per unit of time)

Comment: The select speed is pretty obvious now that you clarified it. Could you give some more informations about the parallelized date ingestion and how this can be achieved in particular?

Comment: How are you running Spark? Parallel distributed processing is inherent to Spark's computation model, assuming you are running Spark in a cluster.

Comment: Jap running Spark in a cluster. I think i know then what you meant with parallelizing the date ingestion ;)

Comment: I quickly talk about it (slides 13-14) on this preso: http://www.virdata.com/virdata-to-present-at-the-bigdata-be-meetup-on-july-9th-2014-in-mechelen-belgium/  audio is quite bad -> needs 150% volume to hear it.

Comment: Jap "data", of course. My bad. Thanks for the preso, appreciate it.